# Не отображается изображения при помощи Picasso

Tags: java, android

Необходимо в галерее выбрать изображения и вывести их в **imageView**.
Запуск intenta:( [библиотека](https://github.com/lovetuzitong/MultiImageSelector))

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MultiImageSelectorActivity.class);
    // whether show camera
    intent.putExtra(MultiImageSelectorActivity.EXTRA_SHOW_CAMERA, false);
    // max select image amount
    intent.putExtra(MultiImageSelectorActivity.EXTRA_SELECT_COUNT, 3);
    // select mode (MultiImageSelectorActivity.MODE_SINGLE OR MultiImageSelectorActivity.MODE_MULTI)
    intent.putExtra(MultiImageSelectorActivity.EXTRA_SELECT_MODE,
            MultiImageSelectorActivity.MODE_MULTI);
    // default select images (support array list)

    startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
```

**path это ArrayList**

```
path = data.getStringArrayListExtra(MultiImageSelectorActivity.EXTRA_RESULT);
```

обращаюсь по индексу к элементам

```
Uri image = Uri.parse(path.get(0)); 
Uri image1 = Uri.parse(path.get(1)); 
Uri image2 = Uri.parse( path.get(2));
```

в Логи выводятся :

```
12-19 13:48:14.138 30515-30515/com.handlingcitizen.handlingcitizen D/selectimage: /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20161218_195456.jpg 
12-19 13:48:14.138 30515-30515/com.handlingcitizen.handlingcitizen D/selectimage1: /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20161218_195505.jpg 
12-19 13:48:14.138 30515-30515/com.handlingcitizen.handlingcitizen D/selectimage2: /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20161218_195510.jpg
```

и вывожу через

```
Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(image).resize(1280, 720).centerInside().into(imageViewUppload); 
Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(image1).resize(1280, 720).centerInside().into(imageViewUppload1); 
Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(image2).resize(1280, 720).centerInside().into(imageViewUppload2);
```

однако, в Layout изображения не отображаются.
Код разметки:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <com.joooonho.SelectableRoundedImageView
        android:id="@+id/upploadImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"

        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:civ_border_width="1dp"
        app:sriv_border_color="#7d8489"
        app:sriv_border_width="2dip"
        app:sriv_left_bottom_corner_radius="5dip"
        app:sriv_left_top_corner_radius="5dip"
        app:sriv_oval="false"
        app:sriv_right_bottom_corner_radius="5dip"
        app:sriv_right_top_corner_radius="5dip" />

    <com.joooonho.SelectableRoundedImageView
        android:id="@+id/upploadImage1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"

        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:civ_border_width="3dp"
        app:sriv_border_color="#7d8489"
        app:sriv_border_width="2dip"
        app:sriv_left_bottom_corner_radius="5dip"
        app:sriv_left_top_corner_radius="5dip"
        app:sriv_oval="false"
        app:sriv_right_bottom_corner_radius="5dip"
        app:sriv_right_top_corner_radius="5dip" />

    <com.joooonho.SelectableRoundedImageView
        android:id="@+id/upploadImage2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"

        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:civ_border_width="3dp"
        app:sriv_border_color="#7d8489"
        app:sriv_border_width="2dip"
        app:sriv_left_bottom_corner_radius="5dip"
        app:sriv_left_top_corner_radius="5dip"
        app:sriv_oval="false"
        app:sriv_right_bottom_corner_radius="5dip"
        app:sriv_right_top_corner_radius="5dip" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: С wrap_content не получится. Укажите в разметке необходимые вам размеры (layout_height например). И в centerInside смысла нет, у вас для imageView указано centerCrop и так.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov
исправил все замечания,но ничего не изменилось.
  `android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"`

Comment: Попробуйте сначала статическую картинку указать (через imageView.setImageResource например). Надо определить с размерами не порядок или в пикассо дело.

Comment: @ Yura Ivanov
такая ситуация: я через `Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);` делаю фото и фото с камеры выводится в imageView. а с галереи нет,попробую как вы  и сказали,только для файла из assets

Comment: Попробуйте `"file:///"` добавить перед адресом картинки

Comment: @ ЮрийСПб 
странно,но я добавлял так file:// и не работало ,а ваш вариант сработал!
Спасибо